# Using sql.date to update DATE field in database with Java

Tags: java, sqlite, date

I'm trying to update the endDate in a tuple, which is of type DATE. I have connected properly to the database through Java, and I'm able to run other queries. I'm 100% I am using the sql.date class and not the util.date. However, it still fails my constraint that I have set on the row of the table. Which is:

```
CHECK(JulianDay(startDate) <= JulianDay(endDate))
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is related to how I format the date that I'm trying to update. See 1 line in the main method. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    updateProjectDeadline(1000, new Date(2026-11-31));
}

private static void updateProjectDeadline(int projectID, Date endDate) {
    Connection con = JDBCLogic.connect();
    PreparedStatement prepared;
    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE Project SET endDate = ? WHERE projectID = ?";
        prepared = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        prepared.setDate(1, endDate);
        prepared.setInt(2, projectID);
        prepared.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The method works perfectly if I insert the date as a String object, however, then the constraint basically accepts anything. So I want to make it work with sql.date object.

I made it work by entering new Date(System.currentTimeMillis), however, this enters the date in as milliseconds in the database, I need the format as yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: There is no date "2026-11-31".

Answer (score 0):

## Numeric literals

One problem is that your code:

```
new Date(2026-11-31)
```

… is passing 1,984 to the constructor of `Date`. That is, you are using numeric literals with a minus sign to do math. Two thousand twenty-six minus eleven minus thirty-one equals 1,984.

You are passing that number to a constructor which takes a number if milliseconds since the epoch reference point of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

## *java.time*

Looking at the bigger picture, another problem is that you are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on these classes. I suggest you do the same.

For a date-only value, use `LocalDate` with a JDBC driver supporting JDBC 4.2 or later.

And, [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961432/using-sql-date-to-update-date-field-in-database-with-java/70961861#comment125446889_70961432), your intended date is invalid. There is no 31st of November. I’ll use the 30th instead.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2026-11-30" ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Hey thanks for the good feedback! Using LocalDate worked much better, and parsed it perfectly into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Any text datetime format other than `YYYY-MM-DD` is useless when used with SQLite's datetime functions.
This makes your check constraint also useless.
You can check it yourself by executing:

```
SELECT julianday('2022/02/02');
```

The result is `NULL`, but:

```
SELECT julianday('2022-02-02');
```

returns the correct result.

So, first update the existing values of the 2 date columns in your table to the correct format:

```
UPDATE Project 
SET startdate = REPLACE(startdate, '/', '-')
    endDate = REPLACE(endDate, '/', '-');
```

Also, the check constraint can be simplified to just:

```
CHECK(startDate <= endDate)
```